# How to use noun + verb + (adj. denoting "other") + adj. + pl. noun?

Tags: adjectives

Is it possible to say Noun + verb + (adj. denoting "other") + adj. + pl. noun without applying the adjective to the first noun? e.g.

```
The Tyrannosaurus rex ate the other nice dinosaurs.
```

This implies that the T. rex is also nice. Is there a way to do this without suggesting that? My guess would be something like:

```
The Tyrannosaurus rex ate the other, nice dinosaurs.
```

Inserting a comma. Is this correct, and if not, is there a way to do this?

Comment: @DarshanBaral This crossed my mind as well, but I want to make it clear that the first noun is a second noun.

Comment: When you ' want to make it clear that the first noun is a second noun' what on Earth does that mean, please?

Does it mean 'there are two nouns'?

Does it mean 'the first and second nouns are not the same'?

Where could any confusion have arisen, unless a noun had been repeated and even then, how would 'the dinosaur ate the other dinosaurs' or 'the T Rex ate the other T Rexes' be confusing'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is found in your desire to use an adjective like "other," or denoting "other." By definition, it includes the subject noun in the group, which means the adjective applied to the object noun will naturally be assumed to apply to the subject noun as well. If you really need to let the reader know that the group of Triceratops whom T. Rex ate for lunch were nice, a subordinate clause, viz. "ate the other dinosaurs, who were nice," is probably your best bet. Although, looking at that, now you have a problem deciding if Triceratops Tartar tasted "nice" or if they were actually kind, good dinosaurs.